# QODBC (Quickbooks), ODBC Mathematica connection string

Tags: jdbc

I am trying to connect to QuickBooks using QODBC driver. I am able to successfully connect when I use RazorSQL but can not figure out the correct statements in Mathematica (11.2) nor can Icconnect with Database Explorer. 
I can successfully connect from  RazorSQL successfully in which they use the following:
Driver Class: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

JDBC URL: jdbc:odbc:QuickBooks Data 64-Bit QRemote
In their driver they have two other boxes:
Login:  "login name"
Password:  "password"
I don't understand how you pass this in Mathematica.  I have looked at documentation but can't seem to duplicate something that works.

I have tried:
    Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

```
OpenSQLConnection[
```

JDBC["sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver", 
  "jdbc:odbc:QuickBooks Data 64-Bit"]]

Error given ----JDBC::classnotfound: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver

and tried this
    Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

```
conn = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["odbc", "QuickBooks Data 64-Bit QRemote"]]
```

During evaluation of In[5]:= JDBC::classnotfound: odbc

```
Out[6]= $Failed
```

I have this but not sure how I got that set up:

```
JDBCDriver["Version" -> 3.1, 
 "Location" -> 
 "C:\\ProgramData\\Mathematica\\DatabaseResources\\Quickbooks \
 Connector.m", "Description" -> Null, 
"Driver" -> "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver", 
"Name" -> "Quickbooks Connector", 
"Protocol" -> "jdbc:odbc:QuickBooks Data 64-Bit QRemote", 
"Location" -> 
"C:\\ProgramData\\Mathematica\\DatabaseResources\\Quickbooks \
Connector.m"]}
```

Would someone be able provide the correct Mathematica statements? Thanks David

Comment: Use the [Database Connections](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/tutorial/DatabaseConnections.html) tutorial for instructions on how to install and JDBC driver for Mathematica.  Details are in the *Installing JDBC Drivers* section.

Comment: I did reference that but am unable to duplicate correctly.

Comment: Edit your post and Include the `OpenSQLConnection` code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is no authentication required by QODBC. You can skip Login & Password & try to connect to QuickBooks using QODBC DSN "QuickBooks Data 64-Bit QRemote". You just need to keep QuickBooks running login to company file as an Admin & try to connect.

Please refer below mentioned article for Connecting QODBC Driver to QuickBooks for the First Time (Video):
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2512

If you are still the facing issue, Please raise a support ticket to the QODBC Technical Support department from below mentioned link & provide requested information:
http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Tickets/Submit

We may need the following information, Please attach below listed files when replying to the ticket.
1) Screenshot of QODBC Setup Screen -- > About

2) Screenshot of the issue you’re facing.

Share Entire Log Files as an attachment in text format from

3) QODBC Setup Screen -- > Messages -- > Review QODBC Messages

4) QODBC Setup Screen -- > Messages -- > Review SDK Messages

Refer: How to take screenshot: www.qodbc.com/links/screenshot.htm

Comment: The QODBC connection is setup already.  It is the string from Mathematica I am having trouble with.  I was hoping someone had done this connection string.  I will call Wolfram for help.